# Vue Computed Property Setup Issues

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following JS that I'm trying to translate to Vue JS. I was told a computed property would be the way to go. I'm a little confused on computed properties still. I know how I want it to function, I want it's input to be the key of the item in the list. And I want the output to be a 'related' array that I can then loop through in sub list. If you are having trouble visualizing, please see this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/oWZEda?editors=0011) Any help would be awesome.

```
// Initialize Firebase
const db = firebase
    .initializeApp({
        databaseURL: "...firebaseio.com"
    })
    .database();

const contentRef = db.ref("a");
const relatedRef = db.ref("test");

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        related: {}
    },
    firebase: {
        content: contentRef,
        related: relatedRef
    },
});

var theKey = "objectb"

function getDiscoverBarContent(key, cb) {
    relatedRef.child(key).on("child_added", snap => {
        let relateRef = contentRef.child(snap.key);
        relateRef.once("value", cb);
    });
}

getDiscoverBarContent(theKey, snap => {
    var snapVal = snap.val();
    console.log(snapVal)
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <pre><code>{{content}}</code></pre>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>'Related' Content</h2>
    <pre><code>{{related}}</code></pre>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>'Results'</h2>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="thing in content">{{thing.name}}
        <ul>
          <li v-for="relation in related">{{relation.name}}</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: My attempt: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/LyyvKW?editors=0011)

```
computed: {
    relatedThings: function () {
    var theKey = "objectb"
        var output = []

        function getDiscoverBarContent(key, cb) {
            relatedRef.child(key).on("child_added", snap => {
                let relateRef = contentRef.child(snap.key);
                relateRef.once("value", cb);
            });
        }

        getDiscoverBarContent(theKey, snap => {
            var snapVal = snap.val();
            console.log(snapVal)
            var output = snapVal
        });

  return snapVal;
    }
}
```

And Error:

> ReferenceError: snapVal is not defined.

Please note, this is my attempt and I am not certain that it is going to work.

I should add...my JS skills are lacking. I know why this issue is happening but not sure how to fix.

Comment: So you actually didnt start trying to use a computed prop here?

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up @FrankProvost, I added my computed property, that makes the question more useful.

Comment: Actually, I think that you are just returning the snapVal in absolutely wrong scope. It's defined in the cb in getDiscoverBarContent so it just doesn't exist in there where you're trying to return it.
To explain computed props, it acts like normal properety in data however there is a function behind it that allows you make the properety kind of "dynamic".

Comment: @DominikDosoudil I think that is the easiest description I have heard, thank you! And I think you are right in your comment about snapVal. Trying that suggestion, I'm new to JS so  trying to figure out how to move it into callback and return the correct data.

Comment: Using @DominikDosoudil's advice, I was able to get the error to go away, and when I console.log the info is correct, however, I can't access in v-for still: http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/LyyvKW?editors=0011

Comment: you are returning `return getDiscoverBarContent` which is wrong. just remove `return` and check [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmjWzY?editors=1010)